# Exim Blacklist -> *domain doesn't work

Tags: exim, blacklist, blacklist-prevention

I have a manual filter in the exim. It was done this way:

In section: "CONFIG". I put:

```
domainlist exim_blacklist lsearch;/etc/eximblacklist
```

In Section: "PREROUTERS". I put:

```
driver = redirect
# RBL Blacklist incoming hosts
domains = +exim_blacklist
allow_fail
data = :fail: Connection rejected: SPAM source $domain is manually blacklisted.
```

So I put a host in each line of the file /etc/eximblacklist.
Works perfectly, the emails are blocked.

But sometimes i need to use a "wildcard".
For example, I like to block all senders of the **.tk** domains.

I thought I'd use: *** .tk**

But it does not work, how do I use the "wildcard"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use wildlsearch instead of lsearch.

`domainlist exim_blacklist wildlsearch;/etc/eximblacklist`

See [here](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-file_and_database_lookups.html) for more info.